# Joomla article alies are not working

Tags: php, joomla

I am getting 404 error while accessing newly created article through alias,
I found that there need to be some thing like this to be worked :

http://yoursite.com/section-alias/category-alias/article-alias

Still showing 404 error, any idea?
If I just use http://yoursite.com/section-alias
It also gives 404 - any idea?

I am using joomla 1.5.23

My current sef settings are:

- Search Engine Friendly: **on**
- Use Apache mod_rewrite: **on**
- Add suffix to URLs: **off**

Comment: Have you create menu items ?

Answer (score 5):

Create a hidden menu (i.e. a menu that is not to be displayed to the site visitors) from the Menu Manager and add the articles as menu items. You need not create a module for this menu as you are not going to display them in the frontend. By creating a menu item Joomla keeps track of the aliases and displays them properly.

On a sidenote, you have search friendly urls turned on... so have you renamed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess? Please check that also.

If you're having problems with certain links giving 404, check all your menus and look for duplication of aliases.

Please have a look at this thread also: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1896103

Comment: YES I HAVE SEF URLS ON, and there is also .htaccess, and its also working for some articles without any errors, but could get it working for newly created articles

Comment: check all your menus and look for duplication of aliases. and remove the Created Date and the published date.

Comment: You mean there must be a menu item with that alias? I mean is there a way to do that just from the article?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create also a menu item which points to this article. Then with the menu alias you can access the article.

Comment: menu item ? inside menue manager there are lots of menus, in which should i create this one ? or should i create new menu with this articles name ?

Comment: Create it anywhere you want. Name it what you want. Just make sure to type in the url domain.com/menu-alias

Comment: I think that this is not a human way to do that kind of stuff... and it is sad... why joomla developers didn't just create that mechanism to work without menus ?

Comment: You mean there must be a menu item with that alias? I mean is there a way to do that just from the article?